# Calendar alert sound on the iPodTouch isn't loud enough is there some "mobile" way to make it louder?

Tags: ipod-touch, audio, calendar, ios

Calendar alert sound on the iPodTouch isn't loud enough is there some "mobile" way to make it louder?

Comment: If you know someone with a MakerBot 3D printer, you could use a victrola horn. http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:6957

Comment: Clean the earwax from your ears. Consult a medical professional if you are uncertain how to proceed.

Comment: @wjlafrance ha ha!  Yes I do know someone with one of those! :)  I was thinking about attaching that to my ear like Rip Van Winkle!

Answer (score 1):

As far as "volume boost" or "overdrive" type features are concerned, I don't think there is one. You could always get a battery powered external speaker.

When I'm out driving I usually plug my iPhone into my car stereo and listen to music / Pandora. It quiets the music (but doesn't pause) to play notification sounds, so it's quite audible.

Answer (score 1):

I would just change the ringer on it to something louder. You can make it different in Settings -> Sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Head over to Settings - Sounds and check whether the volume of the ringer is on its loudest. 
On my iPod there is a different volume for my music and one for my ringer (FaceTime :)